# Remove whitespace and parentheses in filenames with sed

Tags: bash, sed, rename

I have a series of files I need to rename which all have the pattern " (*)" in them.  Eg;

```
001 (1).txt
002 (1).txt
003 (2).txt
```

My desired output is to rename the files to 001.txt, 002.txt, 003.txt. Note the real files vary in length and extension type (this is my test batch).

I have searched the net and SE and come up with the following which gives me the desired output in the terminal.

```
ls *\(*\)* | sed 's/\(.*\)\( (.*)\)\(.*\)/mv & \1\3/'

mv 001 (1).txt 001.txt
mv 002 (1).txt 002.txt
mv 003 (2).txt 003.txt
```

However once I pipe it to sh I get the error below.

```
sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: line 1: `mv 001 (1).txt 001.txt'
```

I know it has to do with the `\( (.*)\)` section.  I've tried escaping the internal parentheses but then that doesn't give me the desired output.  I've also searched for regex ways to say search for the whitespace followed by any 3 characters but have had no luck.

I know there are easier ways to achieve what I want but I went with sed as thus far it was the only thing I could vaguely understand.  Very much appreciate any input into getting the above line working and then considering easier approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a rename command that does just this, but I've never used it.

Your script is close.  Try this:

```
ls -d -- *\(*\)* | sed 's/\(.*\) (.*)\(.*\)/mv -- "&" "\1\2"/'
```

Note that '(' is a special character to the shell.  Putting it in double-quotes cancels its special meaning.

Answer (score 8):

#### Using Bash

You can use this command to do it using strictly just Bash:

```
$ for file in ./*; do mv "$file" "${file/ (*)/}"; done
```

#### Example

```
$ ls -1
001 (1).txt
002 (1).txt
003 (2).txt
```

Running the above command:

```
$ for file in ./*; do mv "$file" "${file/ (*)/}"; done
$ ls -1
001.txt
002.txt
003.txt
```

#### Using rename

Some distros (Debian/Ubuntu) include the command `rename`. You can do what you want like so using this version of `rename`.

```
$ rename -v 's/ \(.*\)\./\./' ./*.txt
```

#### Example

```
$ rename -v 's/ \(.*\)\./\./' ./*.txt
001 (1).txt renamed as 001.txt
002 (1).txt renamed as 002.txt
003 (2).txt renamed as 003.txt

$ ls -1
001.txt
002.txt
003.txt
```

However, Red Hat distros do not include this version of `rename`.

#### References

- [Batch Renaming](http://linux.icydog.net/rename.php)

Comment: Thanks for providing alternate options.  The first one worked as expected however the rename one wouldn't.  I'll do a little research into it and see if i can work it out.

Comment: What's the distro?

Comment: you just saved my life!

Comment: Is there any way to do this recursively?

Comment: @biko - what specifically are you trying to do?

Comment: @slm I was trying to basically perform find and replace on filenames and directory names.  I found this to work (add -type d/f for dirs/files): find . -name '*old_str *' | while read f; do mv "$f" "${f//old_str/new_str}"; done

Comment: on Mac OSX on I had to escape the `(` and `)` and ended up with something like `for file in ./*; do mv "$file" "${file/ \(*\)/}"; done`

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in *'('*')'*
do
    mv "$i" `echo $i | sed 's/\(.*\) (.*).\(.*\)/\1.\2/'`
done
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Worked fine.  Good to see alternative options.